# Reading integers from Txt and summarize it

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, max, min

You are to write a program to compute statistics on a list of exam scores, the Exam Statistics Program (ESP). The input is the name of a text file that contains the number of scores followed by the list of scores. (See the example below.) You should then display the following information:

a. The number of scores
b. The minimum, maximum, and average scores
c. The number of As, Bs, Cs, Ds, and Fs, using a 90-80-70-60 scale.

My problem is: I don't know how to have variable `grade` take numbers.

When I run this program, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
     at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
     at IntegersFromFile.main(IntegersFromFile.java:60)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntegersFromFile 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
        Scanner file = null;

        int grade = 0;
        int min = 100;
        int max = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int a, b, c, d, f;
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
        d = 0;
        f = 0;

        double aA, aB, aC, aD, aF;

        aA = 0;
        aB = 0;
        aC = 0;
        aD = 0;
        aF = 0;

        System.out.println("***Welcome to the Exam Statistics Program!!***");
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of your data file:");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String file_name = input.nextLine();

        try 
            {
            file = new Scanner(new File(file_name));
            }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

        while (file.hasNext()) 
            {
            if (file.hasNextInt()) 
                {
                grades.add(file.nextInt());
                } 
            else
                file.next();
            }

        do 
            {
            grade = file.nextInt();

            if (grade >= 0) 
                {
                grades.add(grade);

                if (grade < 60) 
                    {
                    f++;
                    aF += grade;
                    } 
                else if (grade < 70) 
                    {
                    d++;
                    aD += grade;
                    } 
                else if (grade < 80) 
                    {
                    c++;
                    aC += grade;
                    } 
                else if (grade < 90) 
                    {
                    b++;
                    aB += grade;
                    } 
                else 
                    {
                    a++;
                    aA += grade;
                    }
                if (grade < min)
                    min = grade;
                if (grade > max)
                    max = grade;
                }
            } 
        while (grade >= 0);

        if (aA > 0)
            aA /= a;
        if (aB > 0)
            aB /= b;
        if (aC > 0)
            aC /= c;
        if (aD > 0)
            aD /= d;
        if (aF > 0)
            aF /= f;

        double avg = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++) {
            avg += grades.get(i);
            }   

        avg /= grades.size();

        System.out.println("Total Number of Scores: " + grades.size());
        System.out.println("Total As: " + a);
        System.out.println("Total Bs: " + b);
        System.out.println("Total Cs: " + c);
        System.out.println("Total Ds: " + d);
        System.out.println("Total Fs: " + f);

        System.out.println("Average A: " + aA);
        System.out.println("Average B: " + aB);
        System.out.println("Average C: " + aC);
        System.out.println("Average D: " + aD);
        System.out.println("Average F: " + aF);
        System.out.println("The highest grade was " + max);
        System.out.println("The lowest grade was " + min);
        System.out.println("The average grade was " + avg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. Consistent indentation helps us understand your code and may make us actually want to help you!

Comment: "*I don't know how to have variable `grade` take numbers*" is **not** a good problem description. Tell us exactly what goes wrong when you run your code (post any stack traces). What were you hoping would happen? We can then help you bridge the gap between the two.

Comment: When I run this program, it gives me this error:Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
     at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
     at IntegersFromFile.main(IntegersFromFile.java:60)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the execution of the program reaches line 60, the input for the scanner is "exhausted". You should re-initialize the `file` variable (recommend you to rename it to `scanner` or similar) just before beginning with the do- cycle.

Not quite sure of the logic of the application, especially whether the do- cycle should be inside the while- cycle or not, but I would recommend you to use brackets even if the control structure has only one statement. This you will outline your intention better and will reduce the possibility for errors which are hard to find.